# How make sendmail not relay (under certain conditions)

Tags: mutt, sendmail

I have sendmail configured to relay emails to another service for delivery. However, in my personal e-mail I want to send directly without using the relay.

How can I override the relay settings? I use mutt and procmail to redirect these e-mails which don't work when they are relayed through this other service.

Comment: Please detail the exceptions.

Comment: Using the relay is the default. But when I bounce an e-mail from mutt to another e-mail address or use procmail to copy an e-mail I don't want it to use the relay.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to do this is to create different send profiles for mutt depending on the email address you are sending from.  In your main muttrc you would add a couple lines like the following:

```
send-hook "youremail\@yourdomain\.com" "source mutt_personal_profile"
reply-hook "youremail\@yourdomain\.com" "source mutt_personal_profile"
```

Then you need to create the `mutt_personal_profile` file in the same directory as your `muttrc`, and put in the relevant smtp info just like you would in the main config if you were only using one smtp server for of your accounts. It would be safest to move any smtp settings you already have in `muttrc` into separate files that are "sourced" the same way, so that the settings don't accidentally "bleed" over into other accounts.

*References:*

- *http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/my-number-one-reason-to-use-mutt-managing-multiple-profiles/*
- *http://www.8t8.us/mutt/*